# How can I authorize a Google Service Account without the default credentials file?

Tags: ruby, heroku, oauth, google-api-ruby-client

I have a [Google Service Account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/auth/service-accounts) that my app uses to retrieve data from Google Analytics.

When I created the account I downloaded a `client_secrets` file with all the necessary information for authorization via OAuth, and I recorded the path to this file in an environment variable called `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as per [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#whentouse).

I can now get an authenticated client like this:

```
authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)
```

This method reads the credentials out of the file, which works locally, but my app is hosted on Heroku where file storage is impossible.

[The documentation states](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#howtheywork) that I can either provide this file (can’t), run my app on an official Google Service (won’t), or experience an error.

How can I authenticate my service account without the `client_secrets` file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found the answer in the [source code](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby/blob/master/lib/googleauth/credentials_loader.rb) of the `google-auth-library-ruby` gem.

It turns out that there is another option: take the values from the `client_secrets` file and put them in environment variables named `GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE`, `GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID`, `GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL` and `GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY` respectively.

If these keys are populated, the credentials will load from there. Not a whisper of this in the docs, though.

Comment: More info in the docs now: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby#example-environment-variables

Answer (score 7):

Since this is one of the main results that returns when searching google for "google service credentials ruby," I thought I would add my very recent experience to the list of possible answers.

Though you can do the method mentioned in the first answer, I found an alternate solution that works well with Heroku. I know it has been somewhat mentioned in another post, but the key thing that was left out was how to properly store the full GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS .json file so that it can all be kept within one env on Heroku and not have special characters blow up your app when tryin to

I detail my steps below:

1. Obtain your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS json file by following Google's instructions here: [Getting Started with Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started)
2. That will, of course, contain a json object with all the spaces, line returns, and quotations that heroku simply doesn't need. So, strip out all spaces and line breaks...AND PAY ATTENTION HERE -> **EXCEPT** FOR THE LINE BREAKS WITHIN THE 'BEGIN PRIVATE KEY' SEGMENT. Basically turn the json into one long string. Use whatever method you feel comfortable with.
3. Once you have a single line json file with whitespace and line breaks removed, you will need to add it to Heroku by running the following command:

   ```
   heroku config:set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="$(< /Users/whoever/Downloads/[CREDENTIAL_JSON_FILENAME].json)" --app your-app
   ```
4. For my situation, I needed to have the service account available on initialization, so I placed this in an initializer in my rails app:

   ```
   GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS=Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
     json_key_io: StringIO.new(ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'])
   )
   ```

Notice the `StringIO.new()` method. the `#make_creds` wants a file. So, fake it as such by using `StringIO.new`.

This method works perfectly.

If you need this to work differently on your local machine, you can always store the .json somewhere in the project and reference it through a file location string. Here is my full initializer:

```
require 'googleauth'

#https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-auth-library-ruby/Google/Auth/ServiceAccountCredentials 
if Rails.env == "test"
  GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS = 
Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
    json_key_io: File.open('lib/google/google_application_credentials.json')
  ) 
elsif Rails.env != "development"
    GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS = 
Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
    json_key_io: StringIO.new(ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'])
  ) 
end
```

If you are using a gem like dotenv you can store the formatted json string as an ENV or you can just reference the file location in the ENV

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: If you are fetching a service account token using this method, do it like this:

`authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(json_key_io: StringIO.new(ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']), scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging")`

    `authorizer.fetch_access_token!`


from the [googleauth docs](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby#example-service-account)

Comment: @JeppeLiisberg - Good point. I didn't really address the OP's authorization portion. Thanks for that clarification.

Answer (score -1):

I found this

```
require "google/cloud/bigquery"

ENV["BIGQUERY_PROJECT"]     = "my-project-id"
ENV["BIGQUERY_CREDENTIALS"] = "path/to/keyfile.json"

bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new
```

more detail:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-bigquery/AUTHENTICATION.md

Comment: This does not avoid the need for the .json file.