# How can I store Google API Credentials using Rails Secrets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api-ruby-client

This question is similar to [How can I authorize a Google Service Account without the default credentials file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929650/how-can-i-authorize-a-google-service-account-without-the-default-credentials-fil) but specifically about how to use Rails' built in secrets/credentials functionality.

I realise it needs to be JSON but when I store credentials in a private method and pass that method to `json_key_io` I get a `NoMethodError`:

```
def call
  auth = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
    json_key_io: credentials,
    scope: Google::Apis::ClassroomV1::AUTH_CLASSROOM_ROSTERS
  )
end

private

  def credentials
    @credentials ||= {
      type: "service_account",
      project_id: Rails.application.credentials.google[:project_id],
      private_key_id: Rails.application.credentials.google[:private_key_id],
      private_key: Rails.application.credentials.google[:private_key],
      client_email: Rails.application.credentials.google[:client_email],
      client_id: Rails.application.credentials.google[:client_id],
      auth_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      token_uri: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      auth_provider_x509_cert_url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      client_x509_cert_url: Rails.application.credentials.google[:client_x509_cert_url],
    }.to_json
  end
```

``` NoMethodError (undefined method ``read' for "{\"type\":\"service_acco... ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing I was missing (as pointed out by [miggitymac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2759983/miggitymac) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50881933/145725)) is that the client is expecting an IO object (a file), not a string.

With the addition of `StringIO.new`, this now works as expected:

```
def call
  auth = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
    json_key_io: StringIO.new(credentials),
    scope: Google::Apis::ClassroomV1::AUTH_CLASSROOM_ROSTERS
  )
end

private

  def credentials
    @credentials ||= {
      type: "service_account",
      project_id: Rails.application.credentials.google[:project_id],
      private_key_id: Rails.application.credentials.google[:private_key_id],
      private_key: Rails.application.credentials.google[:private_key],
      client_email: Rails.application.credentials.google[:client_email],
      client_id: Rails.application.credentials.google[:client_id],
      auth_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      token_uri: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      auth_provider_x509_cert_url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      client_x509_cert_url: Rails.application.credentials.google[:client_x509_cert_url],
    }.to_json
  end
```

Comment: I like to create a helper method, so I'm not calling `Rails.application.credentials` over and over. something like: `def google_creds(key); Rails.application.credentials[key.to_sym]; end`

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery just using a local variable inside the method - `creds = Rails.application.credentials.google` would do the job.

Comment: Ya, I suggested the method in case it needs to be accessed anywhere else, but ya the variable would be better if only used here